# How do I check to see if the channel id is equal to something

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make and event that checks to see if the channel id is equal to a specific id, if it is then the bot adds a reaction to that message. I'm not quite sure how to do this and have looked up many solutions but none of them help. There are some errors in the code that I still have to figure out like **channel.id** is not and actual command. Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
await discord.Client.get_channel(<channel_id>)

    if channel.id == <channel_id>:
      await message.add_reaction("✔️")
      await message.add_reaction("❌")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discord.Client` is a type, not a instance. And there is a `message` property inside `discord.Message`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == <channel_id>:
      await message.add_reaction("✔️")
      await message.add_reaction("❌")
```

Comment: thank you so much. also do you know if it's possible to do it for only videos or images? i  was originally trying to make it only react to videos but no one could help so i changed it.